# Cannot run android espresso test with the com.android.test module plugin

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to separate some espresso tests, using the test plugin `com.android.test` that will run as a functional test so no mocking is needed, I just want to use Espresso and uiautomator to do some UI automation.

I already configured the test project with the simplest test case just to check that my main activity is launched:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class LoginTest {
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var mActivityTestRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun test() {
        Thread.sleep(15 * 1000)
     }
}
```

But after the activity launches it crashes, giving the following error:

```
E/MonitoringInstr: Exception encountered by: com.****.****ui.main.MainActivity@9c9faca. Dumping thread state to outputs and pining for the fjords.
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.****.****/change_chart_icons_size with resource ID #0x7f070059
```

Which is strange for two reasons: 1) The main application cannot found the resource ID, which is there (the app runs normally outside the Activity Test Rule). And 2) That resource is not a drawable but a dimensions resource. So it doesn't make sense...

This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.test'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion versions.target_sdk

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion versions.min_sdk
        targetSdkVersion versions.target_sdk

        testApplicationId 'com.****.****.test'

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    targetProjectPath ':mobile'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$versions.dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$versions.dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$versions.dagger_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$versions.support"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$versions.support"
    implementation "com.android.support:percent:$versions.support"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$versions.support"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$versions.support"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$versions.support"
    implementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    implementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:$versions.mockito"
    implementation "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.1.0"
    implementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2')
    implementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2')
    implementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
    implementation 'xmlwise:xmlwise:1.2.11'
}
```

I'm getting out of ideas, I don't know if because I'm using dagger something broke; since I already discarded problems with the `com.android.support` library implementing a module test in a new project.

Comment: Did you find any solution??